# Caddy "listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied"

Tags: permissions

Caddy server would not start and displayed this error after upgrading to v0.9.3:

```
listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied
```

I was running caddy with systemd as user `caddy`.  I checked that the binary was, in fact, owned by `caddy`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're running systemd v229 or later, you can do this without giving the binary capabilities intrinsically:

```
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

Comment: The [caddy systemd example config](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/blob/master/dist/init/linux-systemd/caddy.service) also mentions using `CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`.

Answer (score 31):

It's not a caddy issue, nor a user-permissions issue.  Linux doesn't allow processes to listen on low-level ports by default.

To grant access:

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip $(which caddy)
```

source: [superuser: Allow non-root process to bind to port 80 and 443?](https://superuser.com/a/892391/579353)

Comment: Using `sudo caddy start` seems to work.  Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Probably not, but it's more secure to run caddy as a non-privileged user.  The reason is that if a hacker gets access through caddy, eg with a webshell, and caddy is running as root, then the hacker will have root access to your system.

Comment: I understand.  Thanks